# Shall I override default fields using inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums

EDIT: ChatterOne's answer is good. I must keep it plain simple. No bizarre/wacky behavior is worth to avoid repeating a simple, explicit and useful variable.

**What I wanted (pseudo-code example):** Getting rid of "server" parameters.

```
Config.default_values.server = Server.application
class ApplicationDbConfig(Enum):
    database_1 = Config(Database.db1)
    database_2 = Config(Database.db2)
    ...


Config.default_values.server = Server.warehouse
class WarehouseDatabaseConfig(Enum):
    database_1 = Config(Database.db1)
    database_2 = Config(Database.db2)
    ...
```

**What best solution is:**

Keep your variables explicit. no need to hide it or change a state internally.
Explicit and clear is better. So I shall abandon my objective of getting rid of `s` and keep it simple.

```
s = Server.application
class ApplicationDatabaseConfig(Enum):
    database_1 = Config(Database.db1, s)
    database_2 = Config(Database.db2, s)
    ...


s = Server.warehouse
class WarehouseDatabaseConfig(Enum):
    database_1 = Config(Database.db1, s)
    database_2 = Config(Database.db2, s)
    ...
```

**The original question was:**
Is it worth it to use inheritance to override default parameters? Or do you have a better way to do it?

This is the original code I used to do this, using inheritance. It took too much space and added a lot of noise for the viewer.

```
@dataclass
class Config:
    database: Database
    server: Server
    driver: Driver = Driver.sql_serv_native_client_11
    is_trusted: bool = True
    additional_params: str = None


@dataclass
class ApplicationConfig(Config): server: Server = Server.application
    
@dataclass
class WarehouseConfig(Config): server: Server = Server.warehouse

...

class ApplicationDatabasesConfig(Enum):
    database_1 = ApplicationConfig(Database.db1)
    database_2 = ApplicationConfig(Database.db2)
    ...


class WarehouseDatabasesConfig(Enum):
    database_3 = WarehouseConfig(Database.db3)
    database_4 = WarehouseConfig(Database.db4)
    ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe I'm missing something here, but why don't you pass the server name or configuration when you create the instance and read it in the `__init__` of the class?

Comment: Because I want to get rid of that parameter. Since I have a lot of databases in ServerX, I would have to write the parameter server=Server.serverX many times. It's seems redundant.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean, sorry. You need to write server = config.server only once, and that's in the __init__ method of the base class. Then when you instantiate the class with something like `config = Config(server1)` or `config = Config(server2)`.

Comment: I made a better example of what I am trying to archive. I hope it clarifies what I am tying to do. btw, thank you for your help. I'll try to make it as clear as I can!

Comment: Your latest example is exactly what I meant, that's how you should implement it in my opinion. Maybe I'll try to write an answer and see if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is to instantiate the same class with different parameters, except for a few that may or may not have a default value, I'd do something like this (not tested, just quickly typed), also assuming you have a default driver:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, database, server=Server.serverX, driver=Driver.default, is_trusted=True, additional_params=None):
        self.database = database
        self.driver = driver
        self.server = server
        self.is_trusted = is_trusted
        self.additional_params = additional_params
```

Then you can use it like:

```
database_1 = Config(Database.db1)
database_2 = Config(Database.db2)
database_3 = Config(Database.db3)
database_4 = Config(Database.db4, Server.serverY)
```

But this looks pretty straight-forward to me, so maybe I'm missing something.

BTW, you can also use it with named params, something like

`database_4 = Config(database=Database.db4, server=Server.serverY)`

if you want to be a bit more verbose/explicit (again, not tested, there may be typos in there).

Comment: I'll cleanup my question and accept your answer. After much deliberation, keeping it clear and simple is indeed the best way to do it. Sometimes you focus on DRY'ing your code too much..

Comment: The reason you don't see an __init__ in my code is becaue I use a @dataclass. You should look it up, it's pretty neat.

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer I know about dataclass but that's the point (you have noticed I didn't include it in my code). If something is making your code more complex and less readable, then you need a very strong case to keep using it anyway.